# Images are streatched in the blog

Tags: javascript, css

I have a blog which has few posts with images. Recently a few weeks ago, I found that the images of the home page are streatched as follows which were absolutely fine before.

[image]

Is this a problem with CSS3? I am not much aware of that. How can I edit CSS and Solve this issue? My blog is http://insiderattack.blogspot.com/

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your images are initially fine and not related with `css`, instead it's because of some `javaScript` file that you have probably added recently, try to disable `JavaScript` and load the page with `JavaScript` disabled, it looks fine. Here is an image of your site, i've loaded it with `JavaScript` disabled from `Google Chrome` browser.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Sheikh, It works really well. But I have many widgets in the blog. Is there a way to findout what causes this issue? Is there a specific javascript code which may cause this issue? Is there a way to solve this issue so that all visitors can see it fine?

Comment: It's really heard to tell which `js`  file is causing the problem but one way you can find it out, remove all `js` files or `widgets` and then add them one by one and test the site after making every changes (addition of `js files/widgets`) so you can probably know that which one is the culprit.